# C# Rendering 'player' sprite from differend class

Tags: c#, class, directx, rendering, render

i was wondering how could i display 'player' sprite from Player.cs class. So far everything was happening in **Program.cs** file, witch had 'device' for rendering.
Now i want to do same but using different classes. Do i need to create device for each class to render stuff thats happening within them, or i need to somehow access the device inside Program.cs file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would start by create the device in Program.cs, then if there is another class that will need to render via that device you would pass a reference to the device in that other class's constructor. It would store it in a private field, so it could use it whenever it needs to.

But this may be unnecessary: if you have a central `Render` method, you would probably be looping through various sprite objects and asking them to render themselves, by calling each object's own `Render` method. So you may as well pass them the device reference at that point, rather than making each object know the device it is attached to.